# Google vm firewall, I have open all port, FTP 425 Can't open data connection

Tags: firewall, ftp, google-cloud

I have a problem with uploading or viewing FTP server.
I am able to Connect to FTP server but I can't  upload my file to it
it says error.

```
230 User S2ubp92XXh logged in from ::ffff:xx.xx6.xx3.xx8.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> ls
200 PORT command successful.
425 Can't open data connection.
ftp>
```

I have allowed firewall. Please check this image that I have usefully applied firewall rule or not.
If I don't, then please teach me how to apply firewall rule.
And I have to upload approx 4,500 files to FTP server.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The image is not showing. Please upload it.

Answer (score 1):

> PORT 10,142,0,2,204,3

This command says that the server should connect to the IP address 10.142.0.2 for the data transfer. This IP address is a private IP and cannot be routed over the internet. It is only valid in your local network.

This kind of problem is common for FTP. If the client is inside a local network but the server is in a public network you can use passive mode to work around the problem. If both client and server are in different private networks you would need active FTP helpers on the firewalls/NAT gateways which rewrite the FTP traffic.

Comment: And how can I do this?

Comment: hea help me please

Comment: i have re detailed my question

Comment: @ZomboZi: to cite myself: *"If the client is inside a local network but the server is in a public network you can use passive mode to work around the problem"*. Try if your (unknown) FTP client has a `passive` command to switch passive mode on.

Comment: `227 Entering Passive Mode (185,163,108,43,218,26).
150 Opening Binary mode data connection.
451 Requested action aborted. Local error.`

Comment: it worked last night

Comment: but not now? why

Comment: @ZomboZi: If it worked once but now does not work any longer it is usually because something has changed. Only, you don't provide any kind of information on what might have changed and I have no magic crystal ball to find this out on my own. For example it might be that the firewall no longer allows arbitrary connections (i.e. any port) to the server and thus the data connection from client to server fails.